# Computing frequencies fast in Python

Tags: python, list, collections, counter

I need to count the frequencies of words in a corpus. Usually I use the Counter class from the collections package.

```
from collections import Counter
list_of_words = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'three']
freqs = Counter(list_of_words)
```

However, the corpus I am analysing consists of several million words, so it would be great if there was a faster way to compute these scores?

Here is the code that reads in the words:

```
from read_cg3 import read_cg3

test = read_cg3('/Users/arashsaidi/Work/Corpus/DUO_Corpus/Bokmaal-tagged-random/DUO_BM_0.txt')
count = 0
word_list = []
for sentence in test:
    for word in sentence:
        count += 1
        word_list.append(word)
print count
```

The read_cg3 is a module that reads parsed files and returns a list of sentences. Here is the module:

```
import re


def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def read_cg3(cg3_file):
    """
    Reads a cg3 file and returns a list of each sentence with Token, parsed, and one tag
    :param cg3_file: path to file
    :return: list of words + attributes
    """
    rx_token = re.compile("^\"<(.+?)>\"$")
    rx_attributes = re.compile("^\s+\".+?\"\s+.+$")
    rx_eos = re.compile("^\s*$")

    curr_token = None
    curr_word = []
    curr_sentence = []
    result = []

    with open(cg3_file) as cg3_file:
        for line in cg3_file:

            if rx_token.match(line):
                curr_token = "\"%s\"" % rx_token.match(line).group(1)
                # print curr_token

            if rx_attributes.match(line):
                curr_word = line.split()
                # print curr_word[0], curr_word[1]
                # print curr_word
                if curr_token and curr_word:
                    # to get more tags uncomment this and comment below
                    # curr_sentence += [[curr_token] + curr_word]
                    if '$' not in curr_word[0] and not is_number(curr_word[0].strip('"').replace('.', '')) \
                            and len(curr_word[0]) < 30:
                        # curr_sentence += [[curr_token.strip('"')] +
                        # [curr_word[0].lower().strip('"')] + [curr_word[1]]]
                        curr_sentence += [curr_word[0].lower().strip('"')]
                    curr_token = None
                    curr_word = []

            if rx_eos.match(line):
                # print curr_sentence
                if curr_sentence:
                    result += [curr_sentence]
                curr_sentence = []
                curr_token = None
                curr_word = []

    # cleanup if last sentence not EOL
    if curr_token and curr_word:
        print 'cg3 reached end of file and did some cleanup on file {}'.format(cg3_file)
        curr_sentence += [[curr_token] + curr_word]

    if curr_sentence:
        print 'cg3 reached end of file and did some cleanup on file {}'.format(cg3_file)
        result += curr_sentence

    return result
```

Here is the way the files read by the read_cg3 look like:

```
"<TEKNOLOGI>"
    "teknologi" subst appell mask ub ent 
"<OG>"
    "og" konj <*> 
"<UNDERVISNING>"
    "undervisning" subst appell fem ub ent <*> 
"<|>"
    "$|" clb <overskrift> <<< 

"<En>"
    "en" det mask ent kvant 
"<intervjuunders¯kelse>"
    "intervjuunders¯kelse" subst appell mask ub ent 
"<av>"
    "av" prep 
"<musikklÊreres>"
    "musikklÊrer" subst appell mask ub fl gen 
"<didaktiske>"
    "didaktisk" adj fl pos 
"<bruk>"
    "bruk" subst appell mask ub ent 
"<av>"
    "av" prep 
"<digitale>"
    "digital" adj fl pos 
"<verkt¯y>"
    "verkt¯y" subst appell n¯yt ub fl <*¯y> 
"<i>"
    "i" prep 
"<undervisningsfaget>"
    "undervisningsfag" subst appell n¯yt be ent 
"<komposisjon>"
    "komposisjon" subst appell mask ub ent 
"<i>"
    "i" prep 
"<videregÂende>"
    "videregÂende" adj ub m/f ent pos 
"<skole>"
    "skole" subst appell mask ub ent 
"<|>"
    "$|" clb <overskrift> <<< 

"<Markus>"
    "Markus" subst prop mask 
"<A.>"
    "A." subst prop fork <*> 
"<SkjÊrstad>"
    "SkjÊrstad" subst prop <*stad> <*> 
"<|>"
    "$|" clb <overskrift> <<<
```

My method just reads in one file, this is for testing, the corpus consists of around 30000 files.

Comment: Using Python stdlib only? Using scikit-learn?

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Where's the bottleneck? What steps have you taken to optimise it? How is "faster" measured?

Comment: I'm working on a mapreduce solution for you. Where are the files stored? How are you reading the words out of the files?

Comment: The words are stored in parsed files, I use a method that extracts each words and reads these in a list. The files are stored on my harddrive. So, what I am doing now is essentially reading in the parsed file, getting the words, putting the in the list, and using the Counter method.

Comment: Please post the code that reads the files and `extracts each words and reads these in a list`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget posted the methods.

Comment: ok. This is going to take a while (especially since I can't really test it) - there's a lot of multiprocessing that I can throw at this. Give it some time, and I'll get you something that works by the end of the night

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Looking forward to it! I'm not familiar with multiprocessing in Python, so this will be a step in me learning that as well!

Comment: `read_cg3` reads a file line by line. Now, is it always the case that a sentence in contained on a single line, or is it possible for a sentence to span multiple lines?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget no, sentences never span more than one line. Actually, the file consists of 2 lines for each word, the original word in one sentence, then the parsed word with tags on second sentence.

Comment: Are you sure your cleanup is correct? You add `curr_token` to `sentence` there, but not before. Also, does `result` need to be order preserving (do the sentences in `result` need to come in the same order in which they appear in the file?)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67685/discussion-between-arash-saidi-and-inspectorg4dget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't need to use the tokens, and that your regexes can be done away with. This will count the number of times each word appears in each file:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import itertools

def wordCounter(qIn, qOut):
    answer = {}
    for fname, words in iter(qIn.get, None):
        for word in words:
            if fname not in answer:
                answer[fname] = {}
            if word not in answer[fname]:
                answer[fname][word] = 0 
            answer[fname][word] += 1
    qOut.put(answer)


def getLines(corpusPath, qIn, numProcs):
    for fname in os.listdir(corpusPath):
        with open(os.path.join(corpusPath, fname)) as infile:
            for i, (k,lines) in enumerate(itertools.groupby((l.strip() for l in infile), lambda line : bool(line) and not line.startswith('"<') and "$" not in line.split(None,1)[0])):
                if not k:
                    continue
                qIn.put((fname, [line.split(None,1)[0].strip('"').strip().lower() for line in lines]))

    for _ in range(numProcs):
        qIn.put(None)


def main(corpusPath):
    qIn, qOut = [mp.Queue() for _ in range(2)]
    procs = [mp.Process(target=wordCounter, args=(qIn, qOut)) for _ in range(mp.cpu_count() -1)]

    lineGetter = mp.Process(target=getLines, args=(corpusPath, qIn, len(procs)))
    lineGetter.start()

    for p in procs:
        p.start()

    answer = {}
    for _ in range(len(procs)):
        for fname, wdict in qOut.get().items():
            if fname not in answer:
                answer[fname] = {}
            for word,count in wdict.items():
                if word not in answer[fname]:
                    answer[fname][word] = 0 
                answer[fname][word] += count

    for fname in sorted(answer):
        for word in sorted(answer[fname]):
            print("{} appeared in {} {} times".format(word, fname, answer[fname][word]))

    for p in procs:
        p.terminate()
    lineGetter.terminate()
```

This whole thing took less than a second to process your test file. Note that some of this is due to the overhead of setting up the child processes, so this should scale better to larges corpora.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this worked, have to run some tests to see how much faster!

Answer (score 1):

You can sue built-in `count` function that compiled in C  :

```
dict((i,test_list.count(i)) for i in set(test_list))
```

for better understanding you can see the following benchmarking :

```
from timeit import timeit

s1="""l=[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 3]
from collections import Counter
Counter(l)"""
s2="""l=[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 3]
dict((i,l.count(i)) for i in set(l))"""

print 'using Counter : ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=1000000)
print 'using built-in : ',timeit(stmt=s2, number=1000000)
```

result :

```
using Counter :  8.78281712532
using built-in :  2.91788387299
```

Comment: Note that `Counter` is dramatically faster under Python 3

Comment: @dawg no , its faster than python 2 but not that built-in : this is a result in python 3.4 `>>> timeit(stmt=s1, number=1000000)
6.76945222500035
>>> timeit(stmt=s2, number=1000000)
4.520381794999594
`